# How can I get liblz4.dll

Tags: c#, c, unity-game-engine, port

I am working with Unity3D.
There I am going to use LZ4 library.
So I typed as this.

```
[DllImport("liblz4", EntryPoint = "LZ4DecompressFile")]
internal static extern int LZ4DecompressFile(string inFile, string outFile, IntPtr bytes, IntPtr FileBuffer, int fileBufferLength);
```

But when call this function, I get the error

> "DllNotFoundException: liblz4"

Where can I find liblz4?

Comment: Generic answer - find out where the library is, find out where the program is attempting to locate the library, move the library to the expected directory or point the program to look in the correct directory.  You haven't given us enough to advise more than this.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your application is compiled by Unity so you will need to include the library within your unity project. Check out the answer posted here for more info: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458300/how-to-use-a-external-dll.html